# Qt - How to copy the Qt runtime DLLs to the output path

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll, copy

I need to copy the Qt runtime DLLs libraries to the output path when building.
I did a lot of search , I found a lot of topics but none of them helped.

Comment: for me copy&paste worked good enough :D

Comment: Before @techneaz answers my question , I didn't even know where the DLLs are...

Comment: you could have asked that! :D

Comment: I thought it would be an "easy-way" to do that instead of doing it manually.

Comment: you can install an app called listary. which can assist you to find dll fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most convenient way is to use [The Windows Deployment Tool](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#the-windows-deployment-tool) to deploy your application. The Windows Deployment Tool could be found in `QTDIR/bin/windeployqt.exe`. It automatically puts all necessary dll files in your application directory.

Open your command prompt and add the path to your Qt directory and it's `bin` folder to the `PATH` variable like :

```
set PATH= path\to\Qt\bin
```

Next run the windows deployment tool with your application path as the argument:

```
windeployqt.exe  <path-to-app-binary>
```

This way you make sure that the deployed application would work on any computer and you have included whatever necessary.

Answer (score 1):

1. Compile your project in release mode
2. Find the required libraries to run your application

   For a standard installation of Qt, the libraries can be found in

   > [Qt Installation Dir][Folder name with the Qt Version][Folder name
   >   with compiler type]\bin

   Example: Qt 5.3 installed in C:/Qt and
   mingw4.8.2 32 bit comiplier, the .dll files will be in the
   directory:

   > C:\Qt\5.3\mingw482_32\bin
3. To find out which libraries you need, either you can run the
   application **outside** Qt Creator (the missing .dll 
   files will be shown in the error message pop up) or you can use a program called [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).
4. Copy these .dll files to your release folder where you have the .exe
   of your  application    Example: Qt5Core.dll ,Qt5Gui.dll etc.

Once you have all the required .dll files you can run your application outside Qt Creator.